# get classname of a last <tr> element in a div

Tags: javascript, classname

I have a table like below. As you can see first `<tr>` element's class is "success" and second "active" and third is "success"...etc..

Now I want to do this dynamically. But I can't get last `<tr>` element's classname for add some condition.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

```
<div id="masterContainer" class="bs-example">
  <div  class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">User Information</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>The following table contains some personal information about users.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="success">

          <td><b>First Name</b> <br> som</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr class="active">

          td><b>First Name</b> <br> something</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="success">

          td><b>First Name</b> <br> something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">

          td><b>First Name</b> <br> something</td>

        </tr>

      </tbody> 
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: I see no effort on your part to solve your problem. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:last` selector:

```
$('.table tr:last').attr('class');
```

Comment: which variable are you talking about??

Comment: $('.table tr:last').attr('class'); returns a result and i want to define as a variable.
var className=$('.table tr:last').attr('class');
returns undifined.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle??

Comment: There is no reason to dump a framework on the OP or visitors to do something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

The [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) method lets you pass *CSS* selectors to find nodes you're interested in

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div tr'); // all <tr> descendants of <div>s
nodes[nodes.length - 1].className; // "active"   // the last of these
```